# How to get "session_start", "user" and "screenviews" group by "app version" ? Firebase BigQuery SQL

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am a beginner in BigQuery with Firebase and I try to get the number of users and sessions group by app versions (device.operating_system_version).

Until now, I have this code working (but without group by)

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS all_users,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(user_pseudo_id)
    FROM
      `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'session_start'
  ) AS session,
  (
  SELECT
      COUNT(event_name) as totalScreen
    FROM
      `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'newScreen'
  ) AS screenView
FROM `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
```

The result is fine :

```
Row | all_users | session | screenView
1   | 80        | 150     | 550
```

But when I try to group by app version, the number of users is correct and different for each app version but the number of sessions and screenViews are always the same for all app versions. The code is the following :

```
SELECT 
  device.operating_system_version AS os_Version,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS all_users,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(user_pseudo_id)
    FROM
      `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'session_start'
  ) AS session,
  (
  SELECT
      COUNT(event_name) as totalScreen
    FROM
      `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'newScreen'
  ) AS screenView
FROM `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
GROUP BY os_Version
```

The result is :

```
Row | os_Version | all_users | session | screenView
1   | 9          | 14        | 150     | 550
2   | 6.0.1      | 4         | 150     | 550
3   | 8.0.0      | 9         | 150     | 550
4   | 7.0        | 3         | 150     | 550
...
```

I don't understand this behaviour. It is like if the "Group BY" was only applied on the "user" and not on the subqueries.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It is like if the "Group BY" was only applied on the "user" and not on the subqueries.` That is exactly what is happening, the subqueries are returning the same results for each os_Version 'group'.

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
select
  device.operating_system_version as os_Version,
  count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as all_users,
  count(case when event_name = 'session_start' then 1 else null end) as session,
  count(case when event_name = 'newScreen' then 1 else null end) as screenView
from `xxxx.analytics_xxxx.events_20191105`
group by 1
```